# add extra field inside each page django cms 3.4.x

Tags: django-cms

Hi everyone using this [info](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/how_to/extending_page_title.html#simplified-extension-toolbar) I create a extension of the page like the image. When I click in CMS extension I have 3 more fields

[image]

my problem is that this fields appear only in this area, and I want this extra field inside my page... It is posible... when I click and create a new page is posible to add more fields  that the fields that exist by default

my models is like this

```
class IconExtension(PageExtension):

  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='icons', blank=True)
  description_short = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Short Description")
  description_large = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Large Description")
  content = HTMLField()


extension_pool.register(IconExtension)
```

my cms_toolbars is like this

```
from cms.toolbar_pool import toolbar_pool
from cms.extensions.toolbar import ExtensionToolbar
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from .models import IconExtension


@toolbar_pool.register
class IconExtensionToolbar(ExtensionToolbar):
    # defines the model for the current toolbar
    model = IconExtension

    def populate(self):
        # setup the extension toolbar with permissions and sanity checks
        current_page_menu = self._setup_extension_toolbar()
        # if it's all ok
        if current_page_menu:
            # retrieves the instance of the current extension (if any) and the toolbar item URL
            page_extension, url = self.get_page_extension_admin()
            if url:
                # adds a toolbar item
                current_page_menu.add_modal_item(_('CMS Extensions'), url=url,
                    disabled=not self.toolbar.edit_mode)
```

and I use in my page like this

```
{{child.pageobj.iconextension.description_short}}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please post how are you currently trying to access the extension's fields in your view/template?

Comment: Hi @petr I edit my post, I have a model where I declare the fields that I want, my view in this case is empty.

Comment: hey, still need a bit more detail - where is the child.pageobj coming from? is it a page template or a menu?

Comment: @petr I use `child.pageobj` in all my page that I want to show the info. I don't know what did you need to know exactly

Comment: my question is - what the child is and how does it get the pageobj field?

Comment: I'm a little unclear about what the question is here... Are you asking how you'd add the fields in your cms extension to the page templates, so that when you'd add a new page, these additional fields would automatically show?